# Consuming a RESTful API with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm building a Django application that needs to interact with a 3rd party RESTful API, making various GETs, PUTs, etc to that resource.  What I'm looking for is a good way to represent that API within Django.

The most obvious, but perhaps less elegant solution seems to be creating a model that has various methods mapping to webservice queries.  On the other hand, it seems that using something like a custom DB backend would provide more flexibility and be better integrated into Django's ORM.

*Caveat: This is the first real project I've done with Django, so it's possible I'm missing something obvious here.*

Answer (score 9):

The [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library makes it easy to write a REST API consumer. There is also a Python library called [`slumber`](http://slumber.in/), which is built on top of `requests`, for the explicit purpose of consuming REST APIs. How well that will work for you likely depends on how RESTful the API really is.

Comment: `slumber` is very easy, it does not give much for the abstraction layer. But in some cases may be enough.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like requests doesn't support using cert based authentication.  Seems like I'm going to have to write something myself using httplib.

Comment: Looks like requests now supports cert based authentication? The parameter cert can be a String path to ssl client cert file (.pem), or a Tuple, (‘cert’, ‘key’) pair - available on requests and sessions.

Comment: doesn't this block the whole process?

Comment: Yes requests does not have built-in support for non-blocking IO. However, there are compatibility layers for `gevent` and `concurrent.futures` http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#blocking-or-non-blocking

Answer (score 1):

Make the REST calls using the builtin urllib (a bit clunky but functional) and wrap the interface into a class, with a method for each remote call. Your class can then translate to and from native python types. That is what I'd do anyway!