# Calling Java API from Django

Tags: java, django, rest, api, rundeck

I need to call some Java API from Django, [specifically Rundeck API](http://rundeck.org/docs/api/index.html#running-a-job). I looked around and django-jython is no longer supported. What other ways can I do it? I have looked at rundeckrun (a Python client library for Rundeck API but I need to only use the Rundeck native Java API).

Assuming Rundeck supports REST API, would something like [django-tastypie work](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)?

Edit: As per [Consuming a RESTful API with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590497/consuming-a-restful-api-with-django), tastypie creates REST API and not consumes it. Apparently, the regular urllib, requests module, etc. does the trick.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237894/using-java-based-api-with-django?rq=1) if it helps

Comment: Thanks. But, that one seems specifically for google-android-market. Rundeck does not have a similar Python porting.

Comment: I'm a bit late to this and @mipadi did a fine job of answering the question. Just wanted to note that rundeckrun was specifically created to solve this problem. :)

Comment: Duplicate and outdated, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11663945/930271 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/30259452/930271 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/12732375/930271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you linked to is the documentation for a RESTful Web API. If you're trying to access Rundeck through that, you don't need anything fancy -- you can just use something like the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library to make your HTTP calls. Apps like tastypie are for creating your own APIs, not accessing others' APIs.